# Javascript using Value in Array not possible?

Tags: javascript, php, c3.js

I am trying to use a variable inside of an Array, I get no Error and its not working any idea?

```
var hdd_usage = [12,1232113,12];
var test = JSON.stringify(hdd_usage).substr(1,JSON.stringify(hdd_usage).length-2);
console.log(test);
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 1831.7,1831.7,],
            ['data2', test]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'area',
            data2: 'area-spline'
        }
    }
});
```

Tested here: http://c3js.org/samples/chart_area.html

Actually the hdd_usage is a json encoded string via php, but thats just for testing now. If you get a fix or a better solution let me know it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to add the values of one array to another then you can try the spread operator [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

```
var hdd_usage = [12,1232113,12];    
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 1831.7,1831.7,],
            ['data2', ...hdd_usage ]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'area',
            data2: 'area-spline'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `test` would be a string and inside array it would be a single string element like `"['data2',"12, 1232113, 12"]`. Use **[`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** to achieve the expected result which returns a new concatenated array.

```
var hdd_usage = [12, 1232113, 12];
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 1831.7, 1831.7, ],
      ['data2'].concat(hdd_usage)
    ],
    types: {
      data1: 'area',
      data2: 'area-spline'
    }
  }
});
```

---

See the difference in snippet :

```js
var hdd_usage = [12, 1232113, 12];

var test = JSON.stringify(hdd_usage).substr(1,JSON.stringify(hdd_usage).length-2);
var chart = {
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 1831.7,1831.7,],
            ['data2', test]
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'area',
            data2: 'area-spline'
        }
    }
};

var chartN = {
  data: {
    columns: [
      ['data1', 1831.7, 1831.7, ],
      ['data2'].concat(hdd_usage)
    ],
    types: {
      data1: 'area',
      data2: 'area-spline'
    }
  }
};

console.log(chart);
console.log(chartN);
```